# Uploading xcode project to BitBucket

Tags: ios, xcode, git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I am trying to upload a xcode project to Bitbucket. I am able to commit text files to the repo. However, i am unable to upload the whole xcode project as a single folder. I am new to bitbucket. Your help would be appreciated. I have already signed up with bitbucket.

Comment: "unable to upload the whole xcode project as a single folder" - why? Do you understand how to add a remote and push to it in _git_?

Comment: Yes, i tried to commit, push and pull a .txt file using sourcetree and it worked. However I was unable to push the entire project folder.

Comment: What errors did you get while pushing?

Comment: No errors. The folder is just not visible in the bitbucket.

Comment: Did you maybe use a .gitignore from somewhere that excludes the Xcode Project from Git? Are you sure it is committed in the repo?

Comment: This looks like a problem with your git client configuration. Which one are you using? Do you see Xcode project in it?

Comment: check if the folder do exists physically in finder, since Xcode created groups are references sometimes

Comment: @Dyana remember, you don't push/pull files. Check if you files are in a branch.

Comment: Git doesn't really version folders, it versions files. You will have to put something into your folder if you want to see it. The most common way is to put a .gitignore file into the folder. Add a .gitignore file to the directory, do `git add .gitignore`  then `git commit -m `Adding ignore file'``, the push your folder `git push origin master`, you should be able to see it then